# How to Minus Percentage From a Div Hight Dynamycally

Tags: javascript, jquery

have a code like this:

```
    $("button").on("click", function () {
        var rtop = $("#toprow").height();
        var rbot = $("#botrow").height();
        //rtop = rtop - 10%;
        console.log(rtop);
        var newDiv = $("<div />", {
            "class": "chartBox",
            "id": "chart1"
        }).css({
            "background-color": "yellow",
            "font-weight": "bolder",
            "height": rtop+"px",
            "width" : "100%"
        }).appendTo("#toprow");
    });
```

and I need to to subtract 10% from the height  of `.rtop` then apply it to the `.chatBox` css. What I have done is

```
rtop = rtop - 10%;
```

but this is not working. How can I fix this?

Comment: `%` in _JavaScript_ is the modulo or remainder operator, e.g. `1 % 2 === 1`, `2 % 2 === 0`, `3 % 2 === 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javscript has no percent operator:

```
rtop = rtop - ((rtop / 100)*10);
```

Percent comes from "per cent" ( cent is latin for hundred ). So you have "10 from 100". ;)

Comment: This _specific case_ simplifies to `(rtop * 9) / 10`. In _general_ it's better to do division **last** because it can _introduce_ error whereas multiplication _propagates_ error

Comment: @PaulS. Sir, can you please give me more 411 on "introducing error"?

Comment: It's to do with being able to represent different numbers in binary. Multiplication multiplies an error, so if you have one it gets bigger. Division is way more likely to introduce errors because you can easily make numbers with too many/infinite digits.  I'll give you a quick example `3 * (0.9 / 3); // 0.8999999999999999` vs `(3 * 0.9) / 3; // 0.9`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're always using percentages you may decide to write functions for them to make your code more readable.

```
function percent(x, y) {
    return (y * x) / 100;
}

function add_percent(x, y) {
    return percent(x, 100 + y);
}

function sub_percent(x, y) {
    return percent(x, 100 - y);
}
```

Then

```
// 10 percent of 456 is
percent(456, 10); // 45.6

// 456 subtract 10 percent is
sub_percent(456, 10); // 410.4
```

---

These may be helpful too

```
function undo_percent(x, y) {
    return (x * 100) / y;
}

function undo_add_percent(x, y) {
    return undo_percent(x, 100 + y);
}

function undo_sub_percent(x, y) {
    return undo_percent(x, 100 - y);
}
```

So

```
undo_sub_percent(410.4, 10); // 456
```

And we also have

```
undo_percent(410.4, 456); // 90
// i.e. 410.4 is 90 percent of 456
```

Answer (score 0):

When you subtract 10%, the remaining is 90% which can be obtained by multiplying by 90/100 = 0.9

```
rtop = rtop * 0.9
```